# Python 3 Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my class we are learning how to use functions and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here.
We have to calculate the expense of gas after a trip, and while my program is not finished this is what I have so far.

```
MPG_HIGHWAY = 39
MPG_CITY = 28
GALLON = 2.29

def main():
    total_miles = float(input('Enter the total number of miles driven: '))
    highway_percentage = float(input('Enter your percentage of time on the highway: '))
    gas_expense()

def total_highway_miles(total_miles, highway_percentage):
    total_highway_miles = total_miles * highway_percentage
    return total_highway_miles

def total_city_miles(total_miles, total_highway_miles):
    total_city_miles = total_miles - total_highway_miles
    return total_city_miles

def gas_expense(total_highway_miles, total_city_miles):
    total_miles = (total_highway_miles / MPG_HIGHWAY) + (total_city_miles / MPG_CITY)
    gas_expense = total_miles * GALLON

main()
```

I cannot seem to be able to properly call the variables so it can compute the information after the user input.
Not sure where I'm going wrong here, but any help with pointing me in the right direction would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, you're not passing arguments to any of your functions, nor using the values they return (when you remember to return them).

Answer (score 1):

Your error message should be telling you what is wrong. Upon running your code and providing some inputs, you'll get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "", line 4, in main
>   TypeError: gas_expense() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

So, looking at the referenced code, we find:

```
gas_expense()
```

as a function call, but the actual function signature is

```
def gas_expense(total_highway_miles, total_city_miles):
```

you need to pass those values to the function to keep it happy.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.
So, first you have these constants :

```
MPG_HIGHWAY = 39
MPG_CITY = 28
GALLON = 2.29
```

These constants can be used in all of your functions. But will only be used in `gas_expense`.

You would like to calculate the gas expense by calling the function `main()`?

```
def main():
    total_miles = float(input('Enter the total number of miles driven: '))
    highway_percentage = float(input('Enter your percentage of time on the highway: '))
    gas_expense()
```

Here, you did not use the values of `total_miles` and `highway_percentage` inside the above function, you only enter the values. Also `gas_expense()` will produce an error, because you have defined it as :

```
def gas_expense(total_highway_miles, total_city_miles):
        total_miles = (total_highway_miles / MPG_HIGHWAY) + (total_city_miles / MPG_CITY)
        gas_expense = total_miles * GALLON
```

So the function `gas_expense` needs two inputs. For example : `gas_expense(100, 200)` will not produce an error.

Also, `x = gas_expense(100, 200)` will produce an error. Because this will only do (calculate) what you tell inside the function, and will not return any value. To return the value :

```
def gas_expense(total_highway_miles, total_city_miles):
        total_miles = (total_highway_miles / MPG_HIGHWAY) + (total_city_miles / MPG_CITY)
        gas_expense = total_miles * GALLON
        return gas_expense
```

For example : `x = gas_expense(100, 200)` will result in `x` with value `22.2289377`.

But..I may recommend to not use the same name for functions and variables.

You have no problem with your other 2 functions : `total_highway_miles` and `total_city_miles`. To get the gas expense, the main function can be :

```
def main():
        total_miles = float(input('Enter the total number of miles driven: '));
        highway_percentage = float(input('Enter your percentage of time on the highway: '));
        x = total_highway_miles(total_miles, highway_percentage);
        y = total_city_miles(total_miles, x);
        return gas_expense(x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will help you understand what is wrong in  your code.

```
MPG_HIGHWAY = 39
MPG_CITY = 28
GALLON = 2.29

def main():
    total_miles = float(input('Enter the total number of miles driven: '))
    highway_percentage = float(input('Enter your percentage of time on the highway: '))

    thm = total_highway_miles(total_miles, highway_percentage)
    tvm = total_city_miles(total_miles, thm)

    gas_expense(thm, tvm)

def total_highway_miles(total_miles, highway_percentage):
    return total_miles * highway_percentage

def total_city_miles(total_miles, total_highway_miles):
    return total_miles - total_highway_miles

def gas_expense(total_highway_miles, total_city_miles):
    total_miles = (total_highway_miles / MPG_HIGHWAY) + (total_city_miles / MPG_CITY)
    gas_expense = total_miles * GALLON

main()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely helpful, _especially_ if they don't even mention what they've changed or why.